# Way to plot a second scaled y axis without explicitly using axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is currently how I am plotting using matplotlib. What I would like to include is a second axis that is labelled and is simply the reciprocal of y. I did see previous answers that used the formation of two axes - but is there a simple way of doing it using the more simplistic plt approach below?

```
 plt.scatter(chart_dict[chart][0], chart_dict[chart][1], c=colours[count], alpha=1.0, label=chart, lw = 0)
 plt.ylabel(y_lbl)
 plt.xlabel(x_lbl)
 plt.yscale('log')
```

To summarise, I simply want to plot the data, but have two y axes for the very same data. If I plot: {x=1, y=10}, we only have one point. But if we look to the yaxis, I can see of the left the y corresponds to 10, but on the right, it corresponds to 1/10=1.0.

Comment: Do you mean a second plot (ie subplot)?  Or do you want them overlayed?

Answer (score 3):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1,10,100)
y = x**2
yrep = np.reciprocal(y)
```

If you wanted plots that are overlaid, you can do

```
plt.scatter(x,y,label='x vs y')
plt.scatter(x,yrep,label='x vs reciprocal(y)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

This will give you a single plot with `x` vs both `y and yrep`

---

If you want them in two plots side by side, you can do:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.scatter(x,y,label='x vs y')
ax.legend(loc='best')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.scatter(x,yrep,label='x vs reciprocal(y)')
ax2.legend(loc='best')
fig.show()
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

Since the OP's question was not clear in the first place, the above two plots were shown as the answer. But as the OP is asking for a ***duplicate yaxis***, here is the updated version of the code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x,y,label='x vs y',color='red')
ax.legend(loc='best')
ax2 = ax.twinx() # HERE WE USE twinx() to get a scaled yaxis
ax2.scatter(x,y,alpha=0.001) # they don't appear on the plot
ax2.set_ylabel('yreplica')
fig.show()
```

which produces:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, good answer, but I fear my question was not clear. I need just one pair of x,y data but another y axis, with this y axis scaled from the first.

Comment: Thanks. This is more than one pair of data. So for example, if I plot: {x=1, y=10}, we only have one point. But if we look to the yaxis, I can see of the left the y corresponds to 10, but on the right, it corresponds to 1/10=1.0.

Comment: @Navonod: This was just an example! The `max(yrep)` in my case is 1.0 and the `max(y)` is 100.0 If you want them both to be the same, you can normalise both `y` and `yrep` to `0-1 range`. [Check this answer on how to normalise within a given range](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range)

Comment: yes, but you are plotting two data sets, I only want one data set, but two axes,

Comment: @Navonod: Check the new update, if you still don't think it is what you want, better start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create something like an Arrhenius plot where you have two scales on the same axis, y and (1/y)? You may want to take a look at http://hsugawa.blogspot.com/2010/01/matplotlib-arrhenius-plot.html

[image: Arrhenius plot example]

I don't take credit for the solution; in case the original page disappears, the coding for this is:

```py
""" A function, v(T)=exp(-A/(kB*T)), is displayed as a straight line
on Arrhenius plot where the logarithm of v(T) is plotted
against reciprocal temperature, 1/T.
Some temperatures are manually ticked at the top axis
in the same way illustrated by
axes_grid example code: simple_axisline4.py
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/axes_grid/simple_axisline4.html
"""

from scipy.constants import physical_constants
kB=physical_constants['Boltzmann constant in eV/K'][0]

import numpy as np
arange=np.arange
exp=np.exp

tt=arange(18.,501.)
vv=exp(-0.02/(kB*tt))

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.parasite_axes import SubplotHost

fig=plt.figure(1)
ax1=SubplotHost(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax1)

ax1.plot(1./tt,vv)
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_xlabel('Reciprocal temperature (1/K)')

ax2=ax1.twin() # ax2 is responsible for "top" axis and "right" axis
tticks=np.array([20.,30.,50.,100.,300.])
ax2.set_xticks( [ 1/t for t in tticks ] )
ax2.set_xticklabels(tticks)
ax2.axis["top"].label.set_visible(True)
ax2.set_xlabel('Temperature (K)')
ax2.set_yticks([])

plt.show()

"""
Python 2.5.4 |EPD 5.1.1| (r254:67916, Sep 25 2009, 12:11:02) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
matplotlib 0.99.1.1
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

What you were looking for is the ax.secondary_x/yaxis prompt.

Here an example for wavenumbers to wavelength:

```
ax.plot(x,y,label="data")
# Define Function and reciproce function
def w2L(x): #cm-1 in nm
   return 10**7/x
def L2w(x): #nm in cm-1
   return 10**7/x

# Create secondary axis
ax2 = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(w2L,L2w))
ax2.set_xlabel(r'$\lambda$ / nm') #Name
```

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html